# Problem with Bootstrap 5.3 (Col centering)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, col

The problem is that the three columns are off-center. Attached at the bottom is the code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEeK2.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTSD3.jpg)

On bootstrap version 4, the problem remains the same. Default text instead Cards doesn't work too (Until I write the text-center)

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary" data-bs-theme="dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
             <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                     Dropdown
                  </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li>
              <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex" role="search">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 text-center">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 text-center">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 text-center">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Tried col-4 and it's not worked anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the cards to `d-flex justify-content-center` instead of `text-center`

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary" data-bs-theme="dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
             <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                     Dropdown
                  </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li>
              <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex" role="search">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4  d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4  d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```